# Locally quasi finite separated over unibranch is univ open

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a locally quasi-finite dominant morphism where $Y$ is locally Noetherian. Let $y$ be a unibranch point. Is $f$ universally open on the points of the fibers at $y$?

If $y$ is geometrically unibranch, this is a consequence of Chevalley's theorem on universal openness of equidimensional morphisms over a geometrically unibranch point (EGA4.14.4.1). From this we deduce the semicontinuity of the number of geometric components at $y$ (EGA4.15.5.1).

What is strange is that I don't find the above statement when $y$ is only unibranch in EGA. From
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0F32
we get that $f$ is universally open if $Y$ is unibranch. So I guess we only need to check that if $y$ is unibranch, there is an unibranch étale neighborhood of $y$. This should be more or less obvious from the definitions, but I don't find this result in EGA or the stack project, is this true?

Comment: What does it mean to be universally open on points? In a neighborhood of the point?

Comment: Yes, this is defined in EGA IV.14.1.1: $f$ is open at $x$ if the image of a neighborhood of $x$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)$.

Comment: If we replace unibranch by geometrically unibranch then can't we use the characterization of geometric unibranchness to get the desired claim (e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06DM).

Comment: Yes exactly, essentially geometrically unibranch at $y$= stalk irreducible in the étale topology, so this should be étale local. For unibranch I was thinking about https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BQ0, which shows this is stalk local for elementary étale neighboors. But then it is less clear what happens to étale neighbors.